# How to create MDM Download block

Tags: java, vpn, mdm

I want to create my own MDM Download block for my Galaxy devices, how can I create it?

A picture for example:
[image: A picture for example]

Answer (score 0):

You need an ELM key, a knox sdk, and call the `android.app.enterprise.RestrictionPolicy.allowFirmwareRecovery`

https://seap.samsung.com/api-references/android-standard/reference/android/app/enterprise/RestrictionPolicy.html#allowFirmwareRecovery(boolean)

This will only work on Samsung devices which have a native stock firmware (e.g. Cyanogen or MIUI won't have these APIs).